# Why doesn't Primefaces refresh my button?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, valuechangelistener

I'm building an application that permits users to manage a task. The task monitoring screen can be accessed by two users **at the same time**. Each user can see if the task is currently running and can either stop it or start it. Whenever one user starts/stops the task, the other user must see the task state changement on her own screen.

However, the code I built doesn't work. When a user starts the task, the other user's screen tries to stop the task immediately. Then some kind of "war" starts: first user's screen re-activates the task and the second user's one re-stops the task and so on.

How can I avoid this war ?

Here is my code:

**taskMonitoring.xhtml**

```
<p:poll
      interval="5"
      process="sbbActivateTask" />

<h:outputLabel 
      value="Activate task:" />

<p:selectBooleanButton
      id="sbbActivateTask"
      value="#{taskBean.state}"
      onLabel="YES"
      offLabel="NO"
      valueChangeListener="#{taskBean.switchTask}"/>
```

**TaskBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "taskBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TaskBean {

   public void setState(boolean b) {
      // I deliberately put nothing here ...
   }

   public boolean getState() {
       return TaskManager.getState();
   } 

   public void switchTask() {
       TaskManager.switchTask();
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that when the poll triggers and updates the `<selectBooleanButton>`, it sees the change and fires the `valueChangeListener`, switching it back, thus the race condition. I would prefer not to mix both state and command in the same control.

My suggestion: the same code as the [showcase of the component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectBooleanButton.jsf). I.e.:

```
<p:selectBooleanButton
   id="sbbActivateTask"
   value="#{taskBean.state}"
   onLabel="YES"
   offLabel="NO"
>
    <p:ajax listener="#{taskBean.switchTask}"/>
</p:selectBooleanButton>
```

This way the action will only get triggered when the user actually presses the button.

In order for the button to update visually, you will need to add the `update` attribute to `poll`:

```
<p:poll
  interval="5"
  process="sbbActivateTask"
  update="selectBooleanButton" />
```

Comment: I have added p:ajax but now the method isn't fired when I click the BooleanButton. What am I missing ?

Comment: I have found the problem: TaskBean was missing a setState method. However, the race is over now but the button doesn't update despite the p:poll...

Comment: Correct observation. You will have to use `<poll update="selectBooleanButton">`, see edit.

Comment: Why update on `p:poll` and not on `p:ajax` ? Why not selectBooleanButton in `process` ?

Comment: I think I ought to go to sleep :) Yes, update on `<p:ajax>`. Anyhow, the `update` is the answer. But check whether it is needed for the poll too (test: change state from a user, check if poll updates the visual state of the button from another user).